# How does one save a url to a list or database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, post, youtube

i am currently attempting a project in which i would post a url of a page i  have to a database to be saved. I am working with a mysql database and i already have  one table with regular information for a user. Next i would just want to save a url to maybe another table linked with the users-username  as a primary key to be saved as a list. think of how youtube has your favorite videos saved, but how can i save the urls like that list, as i would need it to take multiple post for different urls all under one user. i have no code yet to show this portion because i am not sure how this would go.

Comment: Please step first to [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). But keep in mind that SO is a community that helps, and no one will do all the work for you. **Did you come up with something yet** ?

Comment: If one link needs to be connected to many users: have one table that has the links/urls, another one that has the connection between users and links/urls. If not: just have a 'blongsToUser' column in 'links' table.

Comment: Well i have a mysql table that has regular user info and whatnot. now i was thinking another table is created to to link together the user table and a new saved_videos table. in saved_videos it would have a link of the username from users table to the saved_videos table  followed by a saved url list

Answer (score -1):

First you will need to add a field to your DB with a `longtext` and `NULL` being true.
You can give it a name that you like, something like "urls_list" .

Then in php you can add to it as and when.

Best way that I have found is to make a string. Then have a separator that you can use to `split` the string in code. Normally the "|" symbol works well.

As an example

```
www.one.com|www.two.co|www.three.com
```

This will be your string in your DB

You can then use in php

```
explode("|", $value)
```

This will split the string into smaller strings .

Doing it this way, means that you only need one table in the DB per user, and can be in the user's info table as well.